# maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object, for counting views

Tags: python, django

I simply want to count the post pages being opened. so there's views field and update. but I get the following error. And I think it's better to put this logic in models.py not in views.py 
models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    withOutSub = 'WO'
    withSub = 'WS'
    WITH_OR_WITHOUT_SUB_CHOICES = [
        (withOutSub, 'withoutsub'),
        (withSub, 'withsub'),]
    with_or_without_sub = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=WITH_OR_WITHOUT_SUB_CHOICES,
        default=withOutSub,
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    embedded_content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)      
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    with_votes = PostVoteCountManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='get_image_path_community', blank=True, null=True)


    def update_view(self):
        return self.views +1
        self.save()
    views = property(update_view)
```

Comment: You have some weird recursion of calling update_view which then calls self.views which then calls update_view forever hence the max recursion error. On top of that you are defining views twice on your class. Finally you will never save your updated view count because you return before it gets to that code. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Nothing here causes any kind of recursion, because nothing actually calls `update_view` and even if it did that method returns before it can call `save()`. So show the full code, plus the actual traceback.